# Latex template in Zim Desktop Wiki

Tags: latex, templates

I have noted that using "zim wiki" one can export a notebook or page in pure latex format(not just equations) too. What is the point of such documents when we have a stand alone TEX application?

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature in the Zim application, which allows you to export as latex code. I would see use of this if the aim is to incorporating it later in another latex document or use that note as the basis for a new latex document.